# Grassmannian of vector bundles with determinant being a square

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, grassmannians, representable-functors

I want to find a classfying space of vector bundles of rank $n$ generated by its global sections with determinant being a square of a line bundle. Stating in a formal way, suppose $X$ is a scheme, define a functor
$$F:X\longmapsto\{(E,\theta)|O_X^{\oplus r}\longrightarrow E\longrightarrow 0, E\text{ is a vector bundle of rank }n, \theta:det(E)\xrightarrow{\cong}L\otimes L, L\in Pic(X)\}.$$
Is $F$ representable by a scheme?